# WCF PerSession service and AutoMapper

Tags: wcf, automapper

where should I put the code for configuring AutoMapper mapping between DTO and EntityFramework Entities for WCF PerSession services?

If in the default constructor, does that mean every session will create an individual mapping and causes lots of overhead on the server side?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration of AutoMapper is global for the whole application so your service should not do any configuration itself. AutoMapper should be configured in your application bootstraper (when the application starts). For example in WCF service hosted in IIS (over HTTP) you can use standard Global.asax and `Application_Start`.